# how to store and retrieve integer value in nsuser defaults?

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I am use the segment control
and store state of segment value
segment control is use for speed type set in speedometer application.

Comment: Did you check the solution I gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this tutorial for better understanding of NSUserdDefaults to store integer and string Value

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/

Answer (score 5):

Tried this?

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:yourInteger forKey:@"your key"];
```

And of course you can get the integer value back using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"your key"];
```